# Evaluating a function of a complex number at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I evaluate $\left[t^ze^{-t} \vphantom{\dfrac 11} \right]^{t=\infty}_{t=0}$, where $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: Using the definition: $t^z=\exp(z\log(t))$.

Comment: Sadly the exponential function has an essential singularity "at infinity", so a casual attempt to evaluate an expression like this there seems prone to ambiguity.  Perhaps you'd be better off backing up a step and explaining what motivates this calculation.  If there is a sensible context, likely there is some way to take advantage of that to get a sound answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression seems to come from the evaluation of an integral, therefore I assume that $t$ is real. Remeber that "evaluating" at real $\infty$ means in fact considering a limit. In your case, this is $\lim \limits _{t \to \infty} t^z \textrm e ^{-t}$. Let's investigate its modulus, maybe it will tell us something.

$$\lim \limits _{t \to \infty} |t^z \textrm e ^{-t}| = \lim \limits _{t \to \infty} t^x |t^{\textrm i y}| \textrm e ^{-t} = \lim \limits _{t \to \infty} t^x \underbrace {|\textrm e ^{\textrm i y \log t}|} _{=1} \textrm e ^{-t} = \lim \limits _{t \to \infty} \frac {t^x} {\textrm e ^t} = 0$$

This shows that $\lim \limits _{t \to \infty} t^z \textrm e ^{-t}$ evaluated in $\infty$ is $0$ regardless of $z$. On the other hand, you'll get into trouble when evaluating in $0$ if $x \le 0$! If $x > 0$, though, your whole expression will be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude is $t^xe^{-t}$, which approaches $0$, we know from basic Calculus.

Comment: I understand that the magnitude is $t^xe^-t$ but why can we not just sub in the values for $t=0$ and $t=\infty$ as we would do in a case concerning real numbers.

Comment: @usainlightning: Even when working with real numbers, you only apparently "sub" - in reality you take limits.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly the expression $\left[t^ze^{-t} \vphantom{\dfrac 11} \right]^{t=\infty}_{t=0}$ was intended to mean $\left(\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty} t^z e^{-t}\right) - \left( 0^z e^{-0} \right)$.

I'm assuming $x$ and $y$ are supopsed to be real.

It $t$ is a positive realy number, one can say
\begin{align}
t^{x+iy} & = e^{(x+iy)\log t} = e^{x\log t}\left( \cos(y\log t) + i\sin(y\log t) \right) \\[8pt]
& = t^x \left( \cos(y\log t) + i\sin(y\log t) \right).
\end{align}
Then one has
$$
|t^z e^{-t}| = t^x e^{-t} | \cos(y\log t) + i\sin(y\log t)| = t^x e^{-t} \to 0\text{ as }t\to+\infty
$$
and therefore $t^z e^{-t} \to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$.

I was about to launch into some thoughts on how to define $0^z = 0^{x+iy}$, but then I realized that since this probably comes from an integral over the interval $(0,+\infty)$, one should really just think about
$$
\lim_{t\,\downarrow\,0} t^z e^{-t}.
$$
Reasoning similar to that above should show that that is $0$.

I'm guessing this came from integration by parts, and I wonder if applying some standard theorems of complex variables might be a better way to evaluate the integral from whose integration by parts this expression arose.

Comment: What if $x \le 0$?

Comment: @AlexM. : Good point; I was tacitly assuming $x>0$. $\qquad$

Comment: Apologies $x > 0$